# Oracle - How to compare varchar2 column value with a parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to compare username in below query and facing error - 'ORA-00904: "userABC": invalid identifier'. I am not sure why extra single quote is getting introduced here. I am doing it as USERNAME column contains username values like 'userabc', 'USERABC' etc.

Query:

```
DEFINE USERNAME = 'userABC';
DEFINE LOWER_TIMESTAMP = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('15-MAR-23 02.15.27.603000000 PM UTC', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR');
DEFINE UPPER_TIMESTAMP = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('15-MAR-23 02.25.27.603000000 PM UTC', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR');
--SELECT &LOWER_TIMESTAMP AS LOWER_TIMESTAMP, &UPPER_TIMESTAMP AS UPPER_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

SELECT
    REQUEST_NUMBER,
    USERNAME,
    USERACTION,
    MESSAGE_TYPE,
    COMPONENT_NAME,
    TIMESTAMP,
    MODULE_NAME,
    PROCESS_NAME,
    VERSION,
    TASK,
    RESPONSE_CODE,
    RESPONSE_MESSAGE,
    AUDIT_MESSAGE
FROM
    MYAPPLICATION_AUDIT
WHERE
    LOWER(USERNAME) = LOWER(&USERNAME)
    AND TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR') >= TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(&LOWER_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR')
    AND TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR') <= TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(&UPPER_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR')
ORDER BY
    TIMESTAMP ASC;
```

Error:

```
ORA-00904: "userABC": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 23 Column: 24
```

Can you please help to resolve this error.

Comment: use lower('&username'), otherwise oracle will take the value, userABC as a column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the substitution variables in quotes if they represent string literals and don't use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` on things that are already timestamps (or twice):

```sql
DEFINE USERNAME = 'userABC';
DEFINE LOWER_TIMESTAMP = '15-MAR-23 02.15.27.603000000 PM UTC';
DEFINE UPPER_TIMESTAMP = '15-MAR-23 02.25.27.603000000 PM UTC'

SELECT REQUEST_NUMBER,
       USERNAME,
       USERACTION,
       MESSAGE_TYPE,
       COMPONENT_NAME,
       TIMESTAMP,
       MODULE_NAME,
       PROCESS_NAME,
       VERSION,
       TASK,
       RESPONSE_CODE,
       RESPONSE_MESSAGE,
       AUDIT_MESSAGE
FROM   MYAPPLICATION_AUDIT
WHERE  LOWER(USERNAME) = LOWER('&USERNAME')
AND    TIMESTAMP >= TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('&LOWER_TIMESTAMP', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR')
AND    TIMESTAMP <= TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('&UPPER_TIMESTAMP', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR')
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC;
```